# How to return the data type: NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, nsdictionary

I want to return the data type: NSDictionary. But main code got empty NSDictionary.
How can I solve this problem? I used JSON method in the function.

```
    func regionDataReturn(rid: Int) -> NSDictionary {
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let urlPath: String = "MY_SERVER/test.php"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var stringPost="test_id=\(tid)" // Key and Value

    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request1.timeoutInterval = 60
    request1.HTTPBody=data
    request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        var err: NSError

        jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        self.navigationItem.title = jsonResult["name"] as? String
        NSLog("\(self.navigationItem.title)")
    })

    return jsonResult
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do like that.

You are calling a asynchronous function for getting the data, your method will return before the data is fetched. You have two option to fix this issue:

1. Use notification, pass a completion handler or out parameter to pass the value back to called method
2. Make it a synchronous call

```
var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil
var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
var data : NSData         =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response, error:nil)!
var err  : NSError
jsonResult                = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
self.navigationItem.title = jsonResult["name"] as? String
NSLog("\(self.navigationItem.title)")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the error was printed.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
#0 0x00000001001d02e0 in Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> () ()

Comment: :D Thanks to your answer. I solved my problem. I understood that asynchronous call cause this situation.

Comment: @SunnyJeon: You are welcome. Asynchronous request won't block your thread, that's the main advantage of it's. So if you use synchronous request you'll have that issue. So keep that in mind.

Comment: I studied the concept of asynchronous call from the professor 2 years ago, but I've forgotten it. Thanks much :D